# PostgreSQL: psycopg2.errors.AmbiguousColumn: column reference is ambiguous

Tags: postgresql

Пробую сделать такой запрос для добавления данных в RedShift:

```
-- Insert records
INSERT INTO target.table (
            collect_project_id,
            project_number,
            project_name,
            connect_project_id,
            project_desc,
            project_type,
            project_status,
            project_path,
            language_code,
            country_code,
            timezone,
            date_created,
            date_updated
            )
(SELECT id, number, name, connect_project_id, description, type, status, path, language, country, timezone, created, modified
FROM source.table
LEFT JOIN target.table
ON source.table.id = target.table.collect_project_id 
WHERE target.table.collect_project_id != source.table.projects.id AND (source.table.created > getdate() - interval '30 minutes' OR source.table.modified > getdate() - interval '30 minutes'));
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
psycopg2.errors.AmbiguousColumn: column reference "connect_project_id" is ambiguous
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Укажите в select явно, из какой таблицы вы хотите брать колонку `connect_project_id`, т.е. либо в select замените `connect_project_id`  на `target.table.connect_project_id`  или на `source.table.connect_project_id` .

Comment: А можете написать исправленный вариант, а то я что-то не понимаю? collect_project_id есть только в target.table

Comment: Опечатался, в сообщении об ошибке `connect_project_id`. Исправленный вариант написать не могу, я ж не в курсе, какое из значений вам нужно в результате.

Comment: Ну, мне нужно вставить в таблицу target.table данные из source.table если target.table.connect_project_id != source.table.id (то есть такая запись уже существует и ее не нужно добавлять (такая проверка нужна, так как этот код будет исполняться по крону))